# jade error during routing. "error undefined"

Tags: routes, pug

trying to route login.jade from layout.jade but getting error "error undefined". layout.jade code:-

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css')
    script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js')
    script(src='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js')
  body
    .navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-static-top(role='navigation')
      .container
        .navbar-header
          button.navbar-toggle(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='.navbar-collapse')
            span.sr-only Toggle navigation
            span.icon-bar
            span.icon-bar
            span.icon-bar
          a.navbar-brand(href='/') Project name
        .collapse.navbar-collapse
          ul.nav.navbar-nav
            li.active
              a(href='/') Home
            if user
              li
                a(href='/logout') Logout
            else
              li
                a(href='/login') Login
              li
                a(href='/signup') Signup

    .container
  if messages.error
    .alert.alert-danger
      div= messages.error
  if messages.info
    .alert.alert-info
      div= messages.info
  if messages.success
    .alert.alert-success
      div= messages.success
  block content
```

I can't get why the error is undefined. the code is taken from `http://sahatyalkabov.com/how-to-implement-password-reset-in-nodejs/` . I have my login.jade and index.jade as well but why this undefined error?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)